# Login to Open Xchange App Suite by Email Address

Tags: php

I've installed and configured Open Xchange App Suite (7.8.0) on CentOS 6 and it is working just fine. I can log in using the username and password as given in this tutorial
[AppSuite Open-Xchange Installation Guide for CentOS 6](http://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=AppSuite:Open-Xchange_Installation_Guide_for_CentOS_6)

However, I want my users to login by their email address and not by username.
A similar question has been asked by saffer001 in their forum, but the reply is not so appropriate.

[Link to Forum 1](https://forum.open-xchange.com/showthread.php?9519-Logging-in-using-full-email-address&highlight=full%20email)

[Link to Forum 2](https://forum.open-xchange.com/showthread.php?8862-OX-login-with-e-Mail-address&highlight=full%20email)

Can anybody please help on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure a few things before this will work:

Install the following packages: open-xchange-authentication-imap, open-xchange-authorization-standard, open-xchange-passwordchange-script (so your users can change their email password within the Ox Suite).

Set the following in /opt/open-xchange/etc/imapauth.properties

```
USE_FULL_LOGIN_INFO_FOR_USER_LOOKUP=true
USE_MULTIPLE=true
```

Set the following in /opt/open-xchange/etc/mail.properties

```
com.openexchange.mail.loginSource=name
com.openexchange.mail.transportServerSource=global
com.openexchange.mail.transportStartTls=[true/false]
com.openexchange.mail.transportServer=smtp://[host]:[port]
```

Set the following in /opt/open-xchange/etc/imap.properties

```
com.openexchange.imap.ssl.protocols=TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
com.openexchange.imap.ssl.ciphersuites=SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```

Set the following in /opt/open-xchange/etc/smtp.properties

```
com.openexchange.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
com.openexchange.smtp.ssl.ciphersuites=SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```

Write up a password change script and +x in /bin/changepwd.sh. Ignore the documentation where it says you can change the script location in /opt/open-xchage/etc/change_pwd_script.properties, it doesn't work, whatever you set it always calls /bin/changepwd.sh

When creating a user, follow this scheme (plus whatever else you need):

```
/opt/open-xchange/sbin/createuser \
  -u [USER EMAIL ADDRESS] \
  -d "[USER EMAIL ADRRESS]" \
  -p "[USER PASSWORD - irrelevant but must be set, will use IMAP pwd]" \
  -e "[USER EMAIL ADDRESS]" \
  --imaplogin "[USER EMAIL ADDRESS]" \
  --imapserver "[imaps/imap]://[HOST]:[PORT]" \
  --smtpserver "[smtps/smtp]://[HOST]:[PORT]" \
  --access-edit-password on [so the user can change their pwd]
```

I've got mine working this way on the same server as dovecot/postfix so I set all hosts to localhost. There may be some changes specific to your configuration that may be needed but in general this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The login source is set in the `/opt/open-xchange/etc/mail.properties`.
Take a look at the first feature:

```
# Set the login source for primary mail/transport account; meaning which source is taken to determine a user's
# login for mailing system. If 'login' is set, then user's individual mail login
# as defined in user storage is taken. If 'mail' is set, then user's individual
# primary email address is taken. If 'name' is set, then user's individual system's
# user name is taken.
# Currently known values: login, mail, and name
com.openexchange.mail.loginSource=login
....
```

In order to use mail as login define `com.openexchange.mail.loginSource=mail`.

Just restart the ox server and it should work!